# Trying to access my HP printer via a device name failed today; would this be a new printer feature?

Tags: web-application, printers

I have an HP printer which uses DHCP to connect to the local network (LAN). My DHCP forces a specific IP address to make it easier on me.

I also added the IP address in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.3.3.3       printer
```

Then I use `http://printer/` in my browser.

That used to work just fine. I'd see the interface and can click the buttons to do a scan (which is why I use this interface the most).

Today, however, it would not show most of the interface. It shows a few blue and gray lines.

I was able to resolve the issue by using the IP address instead of the name:

```
http://10.3.3.3/
```

I suppose HP made an update and somehow checks the name? Why would that make the connection any more secure? I tested on three different browsers with the same results thinking that means the change must be in the printer's web interface and not the browser I'm using.

---

Update:

Looking at the HTTP requests, I see quite a few that receive a 403.

```
GET http://printer/DevMgmt/SecurityCap.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: printer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0
Accept: text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://printer/
Cookie: sid=<some UUID>

Status: 403
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 08 Jul 2023 14:36:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache

Forbidden
```

The same error also happens for the following URLs:

```
http://printer/DevMgmt/ProductConfigCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/NetAppsCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/ConsumableConfigCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/PrintConfigCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/MediaHandlingCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/MediaCap.xml
http://printer/ProductActions/ProductActionsCap.xml
http://printer/FirmwareUpdate/WebFWUpdate
http://printer/DevMgmt/ProductConfigCap.xml
http://printer/DevMgmt/ProductConfigDyn.xml
```

So I think @schroeder comment is right on point. The printer now verifies the `Host: ...` parameter and it has to be *correct* which would be the IP address assigned to that printer.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is actually going on on the technical level from this description. Therefore it is also impossible to get an opinion if this a security feature in the first place and even more to explain it. To get technical details please check the developer tools, look at the network tab, see what requests are failing and ideally find out why they are exactly failing. Then come back with these details if you are still thinking that this has anything to do with information security.

Comment: The more likely scenario is that the web interface uses self-references that depend on the IP in the browser (hardcoded to `$my_ip`). Because your browser uses something else, then the UI/CSS breaks.